# How to extend regex to find multiple matches?

Tags: php, regex, icalendar

This is my current regex (used in parsing an **iCal** file):

```
/(.*?)(?:;(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$))([\w\W]*)/
```

The current output using `preg_match()` is this:

```
//Output 1 - `preg_match()`
Array
(
    [0] => TZID="Greenwich Mean Time:Dublin; Edinburgh; Lisbon; London"
    [1] => VALUE=DATE;RSVP=FALSE;LANGUAGE=en-gb
)
```

I would like to extend my regex to output this (i.e. find multiple matches):

```
//Output 2
Array
(
    [0] => TZID="Greenwich Mean Time:Dublin; Edinburgh; Lisbon; London"
    [1] => VALUE=DATE
    [2] => RSVP=FALSE
    [3] => LANGUAGE=en-gb
)
```

The regex should search for each semicolon not contained within a quoted substring and provide that as a match.

---

Cannot just swap to `preg_match_all()` as gives this **unwanted** output

```
//Output 3 - `preg_match_all()`
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => TZID="Greenwich Mean Time:Dublin; Edinburgh; Lisbon; London";VALUE=DATE;RSVP=FALSE;LANGUAGE=en-gb
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TZID="Greenwich Mean Time:Dublin; Edinburgh; Lisbon; London"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => VALUE=DATE;RSVP=FALSE;LANGUAGE=en-gb
        )

)
```

Comment: [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: Not as simple as simply swapping to `preg_match_all`

Comment: you need to update your regex

Comment: I know - that's why I asked this question for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.+?)(?:;(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/18

Comment: Thanks @vks - appreciate your input. New question because another part of  the parser was using `explode()` and I thought it should be more intelligent and use a regex. Your answer again works well

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `preg_match_all` to get all the match of the string.

The pattern you use isn't designed to get several results since `[\w\W]*` matches everything until the end of the string.
But it's only one of your problems, a pattern designed like this need to check (for each colon) if the number of quotes is odd or even until the end of the file!: `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`. Imagine a minute how many times the whole string is parsed with this lookahead.

To avoid the problem, you can use a different approach that doesn't try to find colons, but that tries to describe everything that is **not** a colon: So you are looking for every parts of text that doesn't contains quotes or colon + quoted parts whatever the content.

You can use this kind of pattern:

```
$pattern = '~[^\r\n";]+(?:"[^"\\\]*(?:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*"[^\r\n";]*)*~';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches))
    print_r($matches[0]);
```

pattern details:

```
~           # pattern delimiter
[^\r\n";]+  #" # all that is not a newline, a double quote or a colon
(?:         # non-capturing group: to include eventual quoted parts
    "                  #"# a literal quote
    [^"\\\]*           #"# all that is not a quote or a backslash
    (?:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*  #"# optional group to deal with escaped characters
    "                  #"#
    [^\r\n";]*         #"# 
)*          # repeat zero or more times 
~
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iY5bJ3/1)

Comment: Works well and an intelligent answer - upvoting. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
(.*?(?:;|$))(?![^"]*")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/1)

or split by:

```
;(?![^"]*")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/2)